# Javascript promise first returns undefined to the consumer then afterwards return the actual result

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

here is the executing function:

```
readCsvFile: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const data = [];
      fs.createReadStream('tmp/data.csv')
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data', (row) => {
        console.log(row);
        data.push(row);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
        resolve(data);
      })
      .on('error', (error) => {
        console.error('error occurred', error);
        reject('readCsvFile error occurred');
      });
    })
  },
```

Here is the consumer

```
resolveAccounts: () => {
    const etransactBankCodes = ['044', '070', '214', '076', '101'];
    debugger;
    let readCsvFileResponsePromise = CsvService.readCsvFile();
    readCsvFileResponsePromise
    .then(
      (result) => {
        return {
          success: true,
          data: result,
          message: 'done processing'
        };
      },
      error => {
        return {
          success: false,
          message: 'failed',
          data: error
        };
      }
    );
  },
```

Here is a controller that calls the consumer

```
const response = CsvService.resolveAccounts();
console.log(response);
```

Here is the logged result. At first the execution skips the `then` function which results in `undefinded`. Afterwards it goes into the then function and executes

```
undefined
CSV file successfully processed
```

I expected only the resolved result

```
CSV file successfully processed
```

Comment: You need to return the `Promise` from `resolveAccounts` and wait for the response, e.g. `CsvService.resolveAccounts().then(response => console.log(response))`. You cannot just try to use asynchronous operations synchronously and expect it to work.

Comment: And it’s odd, because you do things  correctly in the first two snippets.

Comment: Put more gently, `return readCsvFileResponsePromise.then(...` and when you call it, say `CsvService.resolveAccounts().then(response => console.log(response))`

Comment: `resolveAccounts` doesn't return anything, so it is quite expected that you output `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks guys. By adding a promise around ```resolveAccount``` function and using  ```.then``` at the controller worked. However, I now have another weird one.
```
accountResolved: (num, cd) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // resolve(true);
      axios.get(`/foo/bar`)
      .then(
          (resp) => {
            resolve(resp.status === 200 ? true : false);
          }.catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  },
the consuming function does not await the axios call but it works when I uncomment line 3